# How do i measure the O-notation of a for loop?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

i have a question about O-notation. (big O)

In my code, i am using a for loop to iterate through an array of users.
The for loop has if-statements that makes it break out of the loop, if the rigth user is found.

My question is how i measure the O-notation?

Is the O-notation is O(N) as i loop through all the users in the array?
Or is the O-notation O(1), as the loop breaks and never runs again?

Answer (score 3):

O notation defines an "order of" relationship between an amount of work (however measured) and the number of items processed (usually 'n').  So "O(n)" means "in direct proportion to the number of items n".  "O(1)" means simply "constant".  If a loop processes every item once then the amount of work is intuitively in direct proportion to n, but let's say that your exit condition gets hit on average half way through, we might be tempted to say that this is O(n/2), but instead we still say that it is O(n) because the relationship to n is still direct/linear.  Similarly if you were to assess the relationship to be O(7n^3 + 2n), you'd say the relationship was simply O(n^3) because n^3 is the term that dominates as n grows large.

The answer to your specific question is therefore O(n) because the number of iterations is in direct proportion to n.  All that this says is that if N user records take M milliseconds to process, 2*N should take about 2*M milliseconds.

It is probably worth noting that O notation is strictly concerned with worst case and not the average cost of algorithms (although I have started to find that it is quite common for people to use it in the latter sense).  It is always a good idea to specify to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Big O notation answers the following two questions:

- If there are N data elements, how many steps will the algorithm take?
- How will the performance of the algorithm change if the number of data elements increases?

Best-case scenario in your case is that the user you are searching for is found at the first index. Time complexity in this case would be `O(1)` because number of steps taken by the algorithm are constant and do not change if the number of elements in the array are changed.

The worst-case scenario is that your loop will have to iterate over all the users. That makes the time complexity to be `O(N)` because number of steps taken by the algorithm will be directly proportional to the number of elements in the array.

Big O notation generally refers to the worst-case scenario, so you can say that the time complexity in your case is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Best case complexity of for loop is O(1) and worst case complexity is O(N). In linear search best case is O(N) and worst case is O(N). It also depends on the approach followed by you to solve problem. Like for(int i = n; i>1; i=i/2) in this case complexity is O(log(N). Complexity of if else condition is O(1).